# Select the same column twitce with subqueries with different conditionals

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables:

1. Tercero
2. Contacts
3. Contacts_tercero

As in the following image:

[image: Tables]

I have this query:

```
SELECT distinct t.id_tercero,t.nombre,
 (select top 1 c.contacto from Contacto c  where  c.id_tipo like 5 or c.id_tipo like 4)as telefono,
 (select top 1 c.contacto from Contacto c where c.id_tipo like 3) as correo
 FROM Tercero T inner JOIN Identificacion_Tercero IT 
 ON T.id_tercero=IT.id_tercero inner JOIN Contacto_Tercero CT ON
T.id_tercero=CT.id_tercero inner JOIN Contacto C ON C.id_contacto=CT.id_contacto 
where t.estado=1
```

when I run the query, it returns me this:

[image: Result]

same phone and same email, but in contacts table they have differents

Comment: What you want is essentially a PIVOT, though this can be achieved with case aggregation as well. e.g. `SELECT t.id_tercero, t.nombre, MAX(CASE WHEN c.id_tipo IN (4, 5) THEN c.contacto END) as telefono, MAX(CASE WHEN c.id_tipo = 3 THEN c.contacto END) as correo FROM Tercero t JOIN Identificacion_Tercero IT 
 ON T.id_tercero=IT.id_tercero JOIN Contacto_Tercero CT ON
T.id_tercero=CT.id_tercero JOIN Contacto C ON C.id_contacto=CT.id_contacto 
where t.estado=1 GROUP BY t.id_tercero, t.nombre;`

Comment: thanks ! that was what i need